# command to convert CSV file *with header row* to Excel or ODS spreadsheet

Tags: csv, spreadsheet, google-docs-api, libreoffice, file-conversion

What conventional tool for shell scripting allows me to convert a .csv file **with a header row** into LibreOffice .ods format?

Things I've tried, that ignored my headers:

- `soffice --headless --convert-to ods GPW.99.csv`
- `unoconv -f ods -o dir dir/GPW.99.csv`  *# cannot find any -i parameter documentation for csv filter*
- `google docs upload dir/GPW.99.csv`

The last example is even better, sending directly to Google Drive so that I don't have to email the attachment from the `bash` shell, however, the column names are still A, B, C, etc. and not as listed in row 1, which gets imported as a data row instead.

Comment: I am figuring out one way to do this with the Ruby `roo` gem. When I have a (long?) working one-liner shell command, will post back here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[csv2odf](http://csv2odf.sourceforge.net) can do that:

```
csv2odf -H GPW.99.csv template.ods output.ods
```

The -H option tells it to use the header row from the csv file.